# get control of another window instance

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF program, there is a mask window called CoverP3D needs to be operated (to be maximized or minimized) by different UserControls. The way I call it is to instantiate it in corresponding UserControl back-end code - this causes redundancy because I only need one instance.

```
CoverP3D cover = new CoverP3D();
...        
if (cover.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
{
    cover.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
...
```

I need to create many instances like "cover" in the above code which is redundant. How do I get control of the window that has been already instantiated? Is

> Window.GetWindow()

possible? If possible, what dependency object should be its parameter?

Comment: Are you using some DI Framework?

Comment: No, if needed. I can start to use MVVM only for this window.

Comment: Why don't you keep the created instance in a property of parent class?

Comment: I am not clear which property of this window needs to be kept. @Evan Huang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a `CoverP3D` window every time, you need to keep a reference of the created `CoverP3D` instance and reuse it. like:

```
public class MainWindow : Window {
    private CoverP3D _cover; 
    CoverP3D Cover {
       get {
           if (null==_cover)
               _cover = new CoverP3D();
           return _cover;
       }
    }

    ...
}
```

Then update your code to use the `Cover` property wherever you want to access the window. like:

```
if (Cover.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
{
    Cover.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CoverP3D cover = new CoverP3D();
```

This is a *local* variable. If you want to share it, you need to put it in a place where it's not lost after the scope ends. As you have not shown as your program there is no way to give you a direct place, but you should put it as a class field somewhere it makes sense. Maybe in your parent window? You say you aren't doing MVVM yet, so it's hard to tell.

Summary: make this variable a field somewhere, so you can share it and not have to recreate it every time.

Comment: Thanks. Now I define the instance in another class and make it static. When I need to call it, I use the class to call it.

Answer (score 1):

> *get control of another window instance*

**Try this:**

```
CoverP3D coverP3D = (CoverP3D)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CoverP3D>().FirstOrDefault();
if(coverP3D.Count() > 0)
{     
    // Do something with existing window
}
else
{
    //create new instance
}
```

Comment: Hello, in your code coverP3D is not a Window type var, can't use coverP3D.Show(). @tabby

Comment: @water Coverp3d is not window? then how you are using windowState. see edited answer if its throwing error

Comment: Hello I am using another program to test it alone. There is an Exception: System.InvalidCastException. Unable to cast object of type '<OfTypeIterator>d__92`1[WpfApplication1.CoverP3D]' to type 'WpfApplication1.CoverP3D'. CoverP3D is the name of a .xaml but I doubt (CoverP3D)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CoverP3D>() cannot be successfully implemented.                  public partial class CoverP3D : Window{}

Comment: @water are you using the exact code? see edited answer

Comment: I am now putting the instantiation in a class and call it from the class. Your code should also work. Thanks. I have voted up for you. @tabby